# Tomcat silently dies resulting is 502 server error - running as container

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, containers

Tomcat version: 8.0.47
Tomcat is running as a container using: "FROM tomcat:8.0.47" in the Dockerfile.
Tomcat starts up and is able to serve my web application with no problems.

After approximately 7-10 minutes, I get a 502 server error:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your 
request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

When I check the container `ps -ax`, I still see tomcat process running.
When I check *catalina logs*, the last log line: `INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 72786 ms`

When I check *application-specific logs*, there are no errors.

My expectation: How do I figure out what is wrong and why is it silently dying whilst the process is still active? There is 7 minutes of proof that the application & tomcat was deployed correctly since it works with no problems in the first 7 minutes of start up?

Comment: Are you possibly running into an out of memory error? Check the heap size that you assign to Tomcat and verify that you allocated enough memory to the Tomcat process...

Comment: @nwinkler -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M is this not enough?

Comment: You need to look at all the Tomcat log files for the time concerned, not just the Catalina log. Start with the `localhost` log file.

Comment: @EJP I looked at all the logs files. ```catalina.2017-12-22.log  host-manager.2017-12-22.log  localhost.2017-12-22.log localhost_access_log.2017-12-22.txt  manager.2017-12-22.log```. None of them indicate anything at the time of 200 --> 502 http status code change.